# Android - ObjLoader from Android Gaming Book error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, game-development, .obj

I apologize for asking such a question, but I am lost and cannot figure out what to do.
I am reading the book *Beginning Android Games 2nd Edition*. I actually finished reading the book just today. I planned on making my own small 3D Game, just to test my knowledge. Well, my issue is that the ObjLoader that we made for the framework in the book won't show my .obj file. It either just crashes, shows some triangles, or fills have the screen a grayish color.  I have tried making these .obj files in AutoDesk Maya 2013, Wings 3D, and Blender. But none of them show my object I designed. Even just a simple cube. Again, I'm sorry for asking such a question, but I would like to know if there is something special I need to do during exporting to get this ObjLoader to load it? I know for a fact that I am doing the loading correct. It works for the .obj provided. Here is the ObjLoader's code(straight from the book). Thanks in advance.

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.gl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.impl.GLGame;

public class ObjLoader {
    public static Vertices3 load(GLGame game, String file) {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = game.getFileIO().readAsset(file);
            List<String> lines = readLines(in);

            float[] vertices = new float[lines.size() * 3];
            float[] normals = new float[lines.size() * 3];
            float[] uv = new float[lines.size() * 2];

            int numVertices = 0;
            int numNormals = 0;
            int numUV = 0;
            int numFaces = 0;

            int[] facesVerts = new int[lines.size() * 3];
            int[] facesNormals = new int[lines.size() * 3];
            int[] facesUV = new int[lines.size() * 3];
            int vertexIndex = 0;
            int normalIndex = 0;
            int uvIndex = 0;
            int faceIndex = 0;


            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                String line = lines.get(i);

                if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
                    vertices[vertexIndex] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
                    vertices[vertexIndex + 1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]);
                    vertices[vertexIndex + 2] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]);
                    vertexIndex += 3;
                    numVertices++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
                    normals[normalIndex] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
                    normals[normalIndex + 1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]);
                    normals[normalIndex + 2] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]);
                    normalIndex += 3;
                    numNormals++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (line.startsWith("vt")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
                    uv[uvIndex] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
                    uv[uvIndex + 1] = Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]);
                    uvIndex += 2;
                    numUV++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");

                    String[] parts = tokens[1].split("/");
                    facesVerts[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[0], numVertices);
                    if (parts.length > 2)
                        facesNormals[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[2], numNormals);
                    if (parts.length > 1)
                        facesUV[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[1], numUV);
                    faceIndex++;

                    parts = tokens[2].split("/");
                    facesVerts[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[0], numVertices);
                    if (parts.length > 2)
                        facesNormals[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[2], numNormals);
                    if (parts.length > 1)
                        facesUV[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[1], numUV);
                    faceIndex++;

                    parts = tokens[3].split("/");
                    facesVerts[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[0], numVertices);
                    if (parts.length > 2)
                        facesNormals[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[2], numNormals);
                    if (parts.length > 1)
                        facesUV[faceIndex] = getIndex(parts[1], numUV);
                    faceIndex++;
                    numFaces++;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            float[] verts = new float[(numFaces * 3)
                                      * (3 + (numNormals > 0 ? 3 : 0) + (numUV > 0 ? 2 : 0))];
            for (int i = 0, vi = 0; i < numFaces * 3; i++) {
                int vertexIdx = facesVerts[i] * 3;
                verts[vi++] = vertices[vertexIdx];
                verts[vi++] = vertices[vertexIdx + 1];
                verts[vi++] = vertices[vertexIdx + 2];

                if (numUV > 0) {
                    int uvIdx = facesUV[i] * 2;
                    verts[vi++] = uv[uvIdx];
                    verts[vi++] = 1 - uv[uvIdx + 1];
                }

                if (numNormals > 0) {
                    int normalIdx = facesNormals[i] * 3;
                    verts[vi++] = normals[normalIdx];
                    verts[vi++] = normals[normalIdx + 1];
                    verts[vi++] = normals[normalIdx + 2];
                }
            }

            Vertices3 model = new Vertices3(game.getGLGraphics(), numFaces * 3,
                    0, false, numUV > 0, numNormals > 0);
            model.setVertices(verts, 0, verts.length);
            return model;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("couldn't load '" + file + "'", ex);
        } finally {
            if (in != null)
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
        }
    }

    static int getIndex(String index, int size) {
        int idx = Integer.parseInt(index);
        if (idx < 0)
            return size + idx;
        else
            return idx - 1;
    }

    static List<String> readLines(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(line);
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you include the normals in your export, i used this same thing then i switched to unity3d its free now and way better, i tried an obj and didnt include normals and it showed up all wrong, make sure all your normals are correct on the model too

Comment: No, I do not think I did. I will try that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. But, I finally did get it to work. Turns out I forgot to triangulate the faces before exporting.

Comment: hey that might have been what i meant, i remember i had a couple problems with it, i use unity3d now its way better i think, its free now you should check it out, working with models and animations its way better